# Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed. ExecuteReader to get multiple table results

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sqldatareader

I'm trying to return a List(Of DataTable) using a SqlDataReader instead of filling a dataset. I'm getting the "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed" error after it retrieves 4 tables correctly. Here is the function I'm using

```
Private Function ExecuteDS(ByVal SPName As String, ByVal ParamList As List(Of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter)) As List(Of System.Data.DataTable)
    Dim ds As New List(Of System.Data.DataTable)
    Dim dbConStr As Database  
    dbConStr = New Database()
    Using con As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(dbConStr.ReturnString)
        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(CStr(SPName), con)
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 30
        For Each p As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter In ParamList
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
        Next

        con.Open()
        Using dr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If dr.HasRows Then
                Do While dr.Read()
                    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
                    dt.Load(dr)
                    ds.Add(dt)
                Loop
            End If
        End Using

        con.Close()
    End Using
    Return ds
End Function
```

The error occurs at `dr.Read()`. It should return 4 tables but after it gets the 4th, it still goes and tries to do the `dr.Read()` and throws the error instead of just exiting the loop properly. Any insight, I would appreciate it, thank you.

EDIT: Also tried this with the dr.NextResult() and still getting the error at the same line.

```
            Using dr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Do While dr.HasRows
                    Do While dr.Read()
                        Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
                        dt.Load(dr)
                        ds.Add(dt)
                    Loop
                    dr.NextResult()
                Loop
            End Using
```

EDIT 2: Tried with dr.HasRows in an IF statement, still getting the error at dr.Read()...

```
            Using dr As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Do
                    If dr.HasRows Then
                        While dr.Read()
                            Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable
                            dt.Load(dr)
                            ds.Add(dt)
                        End While
                    End If
                Loop While dr.NextResult()
            End Using
```

Comment: You should use [`DataReader.NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.framework.datareader.nextresult.ASPX)

Comment: When I use that, it skips tables in my result. It returns table 0 and table 2 from my results.. so I don't get table 1 and 3 from my result set.

Comment: Try DataTableReader not a DataReader DataRow.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e06d41f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to not test for HasRows if there is no NextResut

In C#
That last While will cause it to leave immediately.

```
using (IDataReader reader = ...) 
{ 
  do 
  {
    if (reader.HasRows())
    {
       while (reader.Read()) 
       { 
           ....
       }
    }
  } while (reader.NextResult())
}
```

Comment: Same error in the same place when I tried it in this manner. Got 4 tables inside my "ds" object in my sample code, then the error gets throw at dr.Read(). I posted my code in the main post as Edit 2. Thanks for your response.